# What is the generating function of $a_n = a_{n - 1} \cdot a_{n - 2} + 3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

What is the generating function of the following recurrence relation
$$a_n = a_{n - 1} \cdot a_{n - 2} + 3 \hspace{3em} a_0 = 1, a_1 = 3, n \geq 2$$
I tried the method on page 8 of generatingfunctionology by Herbert S. Wilf,
Quoting from the book for the convenience of the users looking into this question(p.s : thanks for that:))

> Given: a recurrence formula that is to be solved by the method of
> generating functions.
>
> 1. Make sure that the set of values of the free variable (say n) for which the given recurrence relation is true, is clearly delineated.
> 2. Give a name to the generating function that you will look for, and write out that function in terms P of the unknown sequence (e.g., call
>    it A(x), and define it to be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot x^n$ ).
> 3. Multiply both sides of the recurrence by $x^n$ , and sum over all values of n for which the recurrence holds.
> 4. Express both sides of the resulting equation explicitly in terms of your generating function A(x).
> 5. Solve the resulting equation for the unknown generating function A(x).
> 6. If you want an exact formula for the sequence that is defined by the given recurrence relation, then attempt to get such a formula by
>    expanding A(x) into a power series by any method you can think of. In
>    particular, if A(x) is a rational function (quotient of two
>    polynomials), then success will result from expanding in partial
>    fractions and then handling each of the resulting terms separately.

multiplying by $x^n$ on LHS was easy, it gave $A(x) - 3x - 1$ assuming $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot x^n$.
But when I try the same on the RHS, i am running into trouble. I get
$$RHS = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n - 1} \cdot a_{n - 2} \cdot x^n$$. I do not know how to express the intermediate form attained in terms of $A(x)$. Any hints on how this can be achieved? Because I am a beginner in generating functions, I have to ask this : Is it even solvable? Is there a special name for such class of generating functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to realize that not all recurrence formula leads to a nice expression of generating function, and not all such problem can be solved with the method described here. I don't expect that there is a nice expression of the sequence that you give. Where do you get it from?

Comment: @WhatsUp oh i see. Actually i was just trying to explore while solving some problems on generating functions. Usually, only sum of the previous terms was involved on the RHS, but i was curious about products of the previous terms on the RHS.

Comment: I assume the author presented this method in the context of solving linear recurrence relations (e.g. $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$). You cannot expect it to work in general.

Comment: @Winther oh i see. Yes they look more suited towards linear recurrence relations. But can recurrence relations like these be expressed by a generating function at all?

Comment: For what it’s worth, no generating function is given for this sequence in OEIS with a similar recurrence relation. https://oeis.org/A102846

Comment: @SteveKass oh wow nice find. the sequence is very similar to the sequence considered above. Well thanks all, i guess as everybody say, i will learn that such recurrence relations have atleast as of now, no generating function. Fingers crossed for discovering one in the future!